# How to remove lines with specific pattern and next line

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I am new to Unix and currently I have a large file of various data. In this file there are lines that are now redundant and will need to be removed.

In the file the pattern:

```
<contact contact_id="<number>" txn="D">
</contact>
```

Edit: There are also similar lines to the ones to be removed, an example is:

```
<contact contact_id="<number>" txn="N">
</contact>
```

I have attempted to use `grep -A 1` to pick up the pattern and remove the next line however I am operating on an old version of Solaris and -A is an illegal expression.

As well as this I have attempted to use `sed -e '12442,+1d'` and this just give the ouput of

```
sed: command garbled: 12442,+1d
```

.

Please can you help me with a new solution.

Comment: are you able to install programs/packages on your OS?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am locked down to the basic version of SunOS 5.10

Comment: not sure what you mean with `sed -e '<line number>` (I assume you mean `sed -e '3,+1d' file` for example). If you're using a variable, then you need `sed -e "$lineNum,+1d" file`, but I would expect a range match to work, so `sed '/[<]contact .*[>]/,+1d' file` should work. Note that `-e` is hardly every needed.

Comment: Rather than say "is not supported", please include a copy/paste of the exact code sample being run, with error messages. `sed` is rather fiddly, and `3,+1d` used to work on Sun 3 machines I worked on ; -)

Comment: Thanks for giving that feedback, I've updated it now and the message it gives is `sed: command garbled: 12442,+1d`  when running the command `sed -e '12442,+1d' file.out > output.out`

Comment: Looks like you should be using an XML parser on this XML data.

Comment: see if your `man sed` has a limits section? I would completely expect `12442,+1d` to work. Are you sure about that line number? What does `wc -l file` report. Check for Windows file with `cat -vet file | head -20` if you see `^M$` at the end of each line, then use `dos2unix file` to clean it up. These shouldn't matter, but without seeing your actual file, we just have to go thru list of top 5 problems with files. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use awk?

something like

```
/<contact contact_id=.* txn="D">/ { got_contact = 1; next }
got_contact == 1 { got_contact = 0; next }
{ print }
```

even the ancient awk should be able to handle that. (There might be a more compact solution, but this isn't code golf)

Comment: After testing that code it appears that this solution does not seem to work

Comment: what goes wrong? are the tags mixed case?
Oh, I missed the addition of the similar lines. You'd have to extend the pattern to keep those similar lines. like `/<contact contact_id=.* txn="D">/`

Comment: Did you try `awk '... code of Ronald inside the single quotes... ' orgfile > newfile` and `diff orgfile newfile` ?

Comment: Thank you! My stupidity should have noticed that it would not have worked with the `.*` and needed the `txn="D"` to work. This has now worked like a charm, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `GNU sed` ?
*For those who want to write portable sed scripts, be aware that some implementations have been known to limit line lengths (for the pattern and hold spaces) to be no more than 4000 bytes. The POSIX standard specifies that conforming sed implementations shall support at least 8192 byte line lengths. GNU sed has no built-in limit on line length; as long as it can malloc() more (virtual) memory, you can feed or construct lines as long as you like.*

The next solution starts converting the file to one long line:

```
tr '\n' '\r' < your_file |
   sed 's#<contact contact_id=[^ ]* txn="D">\r</contact>\r##g;
       s#\r#\n#g'
```